# Dynamic iframe height with css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating iframes dynamically using jquery, the height of the iframe is too large, i want to set auto height to this iframe. When data is loaded the iframe should adjust automatically, i am trying to achive this in a click event

Note: I am creating this dynamically, so there is multiple iframes in my page.

```
 $( ".deletephoto" ).live('click',function (event){
 event.preventDefault();
 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this photo?")) {
   var iframediv=$(this).parent().find('#ifarmediv');
   $(iframediv).html("<iframe src='../users/upload' id='the_iframe' class='iframephotoedit'></iframe>");

   var   currentiframe=$(this).parent().find('#ifarmediv').find('iframe');
    $(currentiframe).load(function() {
                      $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height() );
                    });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of iframe on its load:

```
$("#the_iframe").load(function() {
  $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height() );
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/kkSSH/)**

Comment: can you create the fiddle

Comment: Great...what was the problem.

Comment: The problem is after creating iframe i am setting the height, first time when it appears the height is too large, then after 2 seconds it reduces, also i am getting scroll inside the ifarme

Comment: You should try using `setinterval` to change the height rather than on load. let me know how it goes

Comment: i have added inline style='height:22px while creating the iframe, then added $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height()); works perfectly. Thankssss